# Send multiple value on manually triggered event jQuery

Tags: jquery, events

I am sending multiple values to the event handler when manually triggering the event. I am getting the first one but the second one returns `undefined`.

```js
var value1 = 'value1';
var value2 = 'value2';
$('.ContactAddress').change(function(e, value1, value2) {
  $('body').append(value1)
  $('body').append(value2)

  console.log(value1)
  console.log(value2)
});
$('.ContactAddress').trigger("change", value1, value2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='ContactAddress'>
```

**How to send multiple value in manually trigger event**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send params as array to the [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

```
$('.ContactAddress').trigger("change", [value1, value2]);
```

**Note:** As the parameters are not passed when the actual `change` event happens, the parameter value will be `undefined`.

```js
var value1 = 'value1';
var value2 = 'value2';
$('.ContactAddress').change(function(e, value1, value2) {
  $('body').append(value1);
  $('body').append(value2);

  console.log(value1);
  console.log(value2);
});
$('.ContactAddress').trigger("change", [value1, value2]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' class='ContactAddress'>
```

[image: trigger Docs]

Comment: can you pls elaborate to the note part? what do you mean by `parameters are not passed when the actual change`

Comment: @guradio When the actual event happens, i.e. User actually entering something in the textbox, only event object will be passed by browser, so other two parameters will be `undefined`

Comment: yeah i already stated an if condition for that to check if a parameter is passed if no parameter is passed i am not putting any predefined value thank you for clarification.